# Dagger2. My @Module Object cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

But in fact it is. I'm searched others questions for this issue and noone fix my problem. Error state

> network.Repository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   network.Repository is injected at
>   module.LoginModule.provideLoginPresenter(repository)

I use

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5' 
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5'
```

My code

**ApplicationComponent**

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, RestModule.class, WebSocketModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    MyApplication myApplication();
    @PerApplication Repository repository(Retrofit retrofit); // testet without arg in constructor as well
    WebSocket webSocket();
}
```

**LoginComponent**

```
@PerLogin
@Component(dependencies = {ApplicationModule.class},
        modules = {LoginModule.class})
public interface LoginComponent {

    void inject(LoginView loginView);

    LoginPresenter getLoginPresenter();

}
```

**RestModule**

```
    @Module
    public class RestModule {


        @Provides
        @PerApplication
        Repository provideRepository(Retrofit retrofit){
            return new RetrofitRestRepository(retrofit);
        }

 [...]
        @Provides
        @PerApplication
        Retrofit provideRetrofit(...){
             [...]
            return retrofit;
        }
    }
```

**LoginModule**

```
@Module
public class LoginModule {

    @Provides
    @PerLogin
    public LoginPresenter provideLoginPresenter(Repository repository){
        return new LoginPresenter(repository);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class},
```

instead of

```
dependencies = {ApplicationModule.class},
```

---

And ApplicationComponent should have

```
 Repository repository();
```

instead of

```
 @PerApplication Repository repository(Retrofit retrofit); // testet without arg in constructor as well
```

Comment: Hey the answer is correct. However can you explain me, why dagger sometimes suggest me to instantiate inside _DaggerComponent.builder() .myModule(new Module())_ and sometimes not - it shows in CTRL+P as deprecated?

Comment: You need to instantiate the module in the builder if either you want to specify the module directly (for example you want to create a mock module), or you need to create the module yourself because it has an external constructor parameter. `public MyModule(Application application) { ...`

Comment: Ok so far I understand, however I meant that Dagger suggest me to instantiate module and for others component no, whereas in non of my modules (except in applicationModule) I have constructor. 
https://postimg.org/image/f7mbgn2jv/